# When I change an element in a list it changes the other element in the same list too

Tags: python, variables, arraylist

I have a class Triangle that has the attribute "p", which is a list of the three points of the triangle.
(the points are also lists: [x,y,z])
When I try to set the points of two triangles that are in the same list, they change into the same triangle even though I put in different points.

```
outTri1.p[0] = insidePoints[0]
outTri1.p[1] = insidePoints[1]
outTri1.p[2] = Vector3DIntersectPlane(planeP, planeN, insidePoints[0], outsidePoints[0])


outTri2.p[0] = insidePoints[1]
outTri2.p[1] = outTri1.p[2]
outTri2.p[2] = Vector3DIntersectPlane(planeP, planeN, insidePoints[1], outsidePoints[0])
```

(outTri1 is a reference to the first Triangle in the list and outTri2 is a reference to the second Triangle in the list)

up until the 3rd line, outTri1 has the points that I want him to have
but when I start to touch the second triangle(outTri2) it changes both of the triangles

Comment: Please provide a complete example that can be run and demonstrates the problem!

Comment: how do you define triangle class?

Comment: class Triangle3D():
    def __init__(self, points= [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], color = (0,0,0)):
        self.p = points
        self.color = color